# Java: pick several different random numbers from array in one time

Tags: java, arrays

Could someone tell me how can I pick several different random numbers from an array at one time?
For example, there is a long int array. I want to pick 7 numbers from it. All the numbers mustn't be the same and sort them by increase sequence.

```
Random random = new Random();
int a = mixColor[random.nextInt(mixColor.length)];
int b = mixCoor[random.nextInt(mixCoor.length)];
int c = mixCoor[random.nextInt(mixCoor.length)];
int d = mixCoor[random.nextInt(mixCoor.length)];
int e = mixCoor[random.nextInt(mixCoor.length)];
while(b!=c && c!=d && b!=d) {
   b = mixCoor[random.nextInt(mixCoor.length)];
   c = mixCoor[random.nextInt(mixCoor.length)];
   d = mixCoor[random.nextInt(mixCoor.length)];
}
```

`mixColor[]` and `mixCoor[]` are long int arrays. I can do in this way, but if I want to pick more numbers this will be really complicated. And I need to sort them as well. Someone get good ideas?

Comment: Depend on how big your collection is, you may use shuffle and then pick up the first several elements as required. You probably want to benchmark this - your collection might be big enough and shuffle could be slow, which then cancels the simplicity that you get out of this. Here is the spec for [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: A better way would be to use a `Random` number gen and see if the picked list already has the number at the generated index. Then sort using `Collections`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this method:

```
public static int[] pickNRandom(int[] array, int n) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
    for (int i : array)
        list.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    int[] answer = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        answer[i] = list.get(i);
    Arrays.sort(answer);

    return answer;

}
```

Use it like this:

```
int[] mixColor = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
int[] randomPicks = pickNRandom(mixColor, 5);
```

The method guarantees that exactly `n` elements are picked at random, and that they will be returned sorted. It also guarantees that no element will be picked more than once, and the resulting array won't have duplicates, as long as the input array is duplicate-free.

The above code works fine, but it's cumbersome having to switch back and forth between `int` and `Integer`, and it might be slow if the input array is big (say, > 100.000 elements). Test it first, and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random gen = new Random();
int max = mixCoor.length; // Maximum Random value to generate

ArrayList<Integer> picked = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // List of picked numbers

for(int i = 0; i < numToBePicked; i++) {
  int index = gen.nextInt(max);
  if(!picked.contains(mixCoor[index]) // If the number isn't already picked
    picked.add(mixCoor[index]); // Add it to the "picked" list
}

Collections.sort(picked); // Sort the picked numbers into ascending order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything you want using the existing java API:

```
public static Integer[] pickRandom(Integer[] array, int number) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    list = list.subList(0, number);
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list.toArray(new Integer[number]);
}
```

Notes: You need the call this with an `Integer[]`, rather than `int[]`, so you'll have to convert this yourself. Also, while "efficient" in terms of code size and complexity, this would not be that efficient performance-wise (although it might still be usable). This code would be simpler still if you had a `List<Integer>` to start with.

Answer (score -1):

```
Random random  new Random();
for (int i=0;i<7;i++){
int a = mixColor[random.nextInt()%mixColor.length];
}
```

of course,you can use a seed for the random and get more randomized numbers

Comment: This answer is missing several things that the OP asked for: cannot repeat the random numbers and sorting. See Jon's answer above.